# Express Routing: multiple URLs to the same route

Tags: express, routes

I'm trying to make the multiple URLs work on a single express route. How can I make the following URLs all route to the same page?

- https://example.com/page-slug-name
- https://example.com/page-slug-name/amp
- https://example.com
- https://example.com/amp

It seems like this should work but it's not:

```
router.get("/:slug?(/amp)?", function(req, res, next) {

  if (!req.params.slug) {
    req.params.slug = 'home'
  }

  getData(slug, function(err, data){

    res.render('index', data)

  });

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have it in single express route by placing multiple URLS inside an array.
In your case, this will be

```
  app.get(['/', '/:slug', '/amp', '/:slug/amp'], function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.params.slug)
      req.params.slug = 'home'
    getData(slug, function(err, data){
      res.render('index', data)
    });
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an anonymous function as the route's controller, you can give it a name and pass the name to `router.get`. You can then have several `router.get`s that points to the same function.

```
function slugController(req, res, next) {

  if (!req.params.slug) {
    req.params.slug = 'home'
  }

  getData(slug, function(err, data){

    res.render('index', data)

  });

});

router.get("/page-slug-name", slugController);
router.get("/page-slug-name/amp", slugController);
router.get("/", slugController);
router.get("/amp", slugController);
```

This works best if there only are a couple of routes.

If you have a ton of routes you have to use the regex stuff that's mentioned in the [manual](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). I don't see any pattern in your URLs though, so it's a bit hard to come up with a good solution using regex.

Comment: That did it. I had to rearrange my routes so that  "/" an "/amp" came before the slug routes though. Thanks for the help :)